# Slide out control drawer or container

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to achieve a layout that is depicted in the diagram I made below.

I have a table with multiple rows and 2 columns of information. What I would like is to have a button (represented by the '>' angle bracket) that when clicked causes a "drawer" of button to slide out from the left column. I would like it to just overlay the row and not push any of the content when it opens. It would be best if it were the same height as the row.

[image: design]

I tried it out in JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ewcyors4/), but was not able to achieve what I'm after.

**HTML:**

```html
  <body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some text 1</td>
        <td>
          <div id="outer">
          <div>
          <button id="showPanel">></button>
          </div>
          <div id="buttonDrawer">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
            <button>btn3</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>status text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#buttonDrawer {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showPanel').click(function() {
      $('#buttonDrawer').animate({
      width: 150
      });
  });
});
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ewcyors4/1/

Comment: @banzomaikaka That's great, but I really do prefer the width animation so there's more of a "sliding out" effect rather than just a translation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `#buttonDrawer` css to

```
#buttonDrawer {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space:nowrap;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  bottom:0;
  background:#ccc;
  z-index:1;
}
```

and the `td`

```
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
```

---

**Working example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showPanel').click(function() {
      $('#buttonDrawer').animate({
      width: 150
      });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

#buttonDrawer {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space:nowrap;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:#ccc;
  left:100%;
  z-index:1;
}

#outer {
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some text 1</td>
      <td>
        <div id="outer">
          <div>
            <button id="showPanel">></button>
          </div>
          <div id="buttonDrawer">
            <button>btn1</button>
            <button>btn2</button>
            <button>btn3</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>status text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed some of the code a bit, let me know if you have any questions about what does what.

Importantly, switched to classes, much easier than having a hundred id's with different names. Used `(this)` to control which table row we were working in.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/5whk7kup/) to play with.

A [second fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/rvkum9L7/) with the slide out to cover instead of slide content to the side.

```js
$('.showPanel').click(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('tr').find('.buttonDrawer').hasClass('open')) { // if open close it
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.buttonDrawer').removeClass('open');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.showPanel').text('>');
  } else { // if closed open it
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.buttonDrawer').addClass('open');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.showPanel').text('<');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.status-cell {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.status-blocks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.buttonDrawer {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.open {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

button {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some text 1</td>
      <td>
        <div id="outer">
          <div>
            <button class="showPanel">&gt;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="status-cell">
        <div class="status-blocks buttonDrawer">
          <button>btn1</button>
          <button>btn2</button>
          <button>btn3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="status-blocks">status text</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some text 2</td>
      <td>
        <div id="outer">
          <div>
            <button class="showPanel">&gt;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="status-cell">
        <div class="status-blocks buttonDrawer">
          <button>btn1</button>
          <button>btn2</button>
          <button>btn3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="status-blocks">status text</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some text 3</td>
      <td>
        <div id="outer">
          <div>
            <button class="showPanel">&gt;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="status-cell">
        <div class="status-blocks buttonDrawer">
          <button>btn1</button>
          <button>btn2</button>
          <button>btn3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="status-blocks">status text</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is brilliant, but I won't give it the check only because the solution pushes the status text around, whereas I prefer the overlay. Really appreciate what you did and will look to incorporate bits of this into the answer from @Gaby

Comment: @EugeneS Here's a second fiddle to play with, it has a slide out to cover affect. It might help you out a little though I changed the code quite a bit. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/rvkum9L7/